# how to get rid of nested <span> tags

Tags: regex, tags, tinymce, nested

I use tinyMCE for creating html colored text.
The output is like:

```
<span style="color:red"> This is red <span style="green"> This is green </span> and suddenly red again</span>
```

But i definitely need it like this:

```
<span style="color:red"> This is red </span><span style="green"> This is green </span><span style="color:red"> and suddenly red again</span>
```

Is there any way, to process this automatically? be it regex, or a tinyMCE-function? I don't get it, and I'm searching and trying for days.
Thanks!!

Jakob

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546).  Instead, use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jakob. 
Very good question. It's tricky, but I can help you.

Add this here above or under your form.
First step: it removes format, and thusly splits the <span>-tag
Second step: new <span> is created

ERGO: no nesting!!! exactly as you wanted it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('removeFormat');tinyMCE.execCommand('forecolor', true, 'FF0000')">[ amazing color change]</a>
```

You don't have to thank me, it was a pleasure.

Greetings

Comment: Wow, that is so nice. This was my first post, and I got helped in less than 24 hours. That is amazing, thank you stackoverflow.com. Thank you so much. :D